# Jenkins: how to rename and copy built files on a Windows via a remote agent using Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following script that I run to build my the Windows version of my Ionic application on a Windows machine. Jenkins is installed on a Mac, and the following run a remote agent on a Windows machine.

```
    pipeline {
      agent none
      stages {
        
        stage('Build Windows') {
           agent { 
            label 'windows'
          }
           environment {
              PATH="C:\\Windows\\System32;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Users\\pchapman\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10"
          }
          steps {
            checkout scm
            println "installing packages"
            bat 'npm install'
            
            println "Building"
            bat 'ionic cordova build windows --prod --release -- --archs="x86 x64 arm" --buildConfig=platform_build_files\\windows\\build.config'
            
            println "Copy built images"
                   
            bat 'ren platforms\\windows\\AppPackages\\CordovaApp.* platforms\\windows\\AppPackages\\MyApp.*'
            bat 'if not exist c:\\MyAppBuilds mkdir c:\\MyApp'
            bat 'copy platforms\\windows\\AppPackages\\*.appxupload c:\\MyAppBuilds'            
        }   
      }  
    }
```

Everything works until the 3 bat steps after the println "Copy built images" where I see the following error...

```
[Pipeline] echo
    Copy built images
    [Pipeline] bat

    c:\jenkins\workspace\myApp>ren platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.* platforms\windows\AppPackages\MyApp.* 
    The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I also tried put the `bat`command inside a `script: {}`block but this did not work either.

The other bat commands work (eg bat ionic cordova build windows`) so wondering why these simple cmd prompt commands do not?

Am I able to do the above, and if so, what is the syntax I need to use?

Comment: Maybe an character escaping issue?  Can you run that command without Jenkins?

Comment: @Alex - how stupid am I!? Yes you are right, I tested the command and then added the paths. The dest filename should NOT have the path. Should be `bat 'ren platforms\\windows\\AppPackages\\CordovaApp.* MyApp.*'` and that works fine, Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed by way of changing a malformed or incorrect path.

Comment: Yes, Should be bat 'ren platforms\\windows\\AppPackages\\CordovaApp.* MyApp.*' and that works fine. So the actual method being used is correct (ie bat)